# Disable header in a column and keep sorting with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a table and I need that the header of a particular column be disable but this column need to be sorted by JQUERY, do somebody knows how do I have to do it?

Here is the jQuery code:

```
function TaskSortingAndFiltering() {   
    var taskTable = $("#TaskTable");

    if (taskTable != null && taskTable.attr('rows') != undefined) {
        // If exists at least one Task, set the paging and sorting to the table
        if (taskTable.attr('rows').length > 1) {
            $("#TaskTable")
                    .tablesorter({
                        sortList: [[2, 0], [1, 0]],
                        headers: {
                            0: { sorter: false },
                            2: { sorter: 'custom-date' }
                        }
                    })
                .tablesorterPager({
                    container: $("#pager"),
                    size: 10
                });
        }
    }

}

$(document).ready(function () {

    // add parser through the tablesorter addParser method
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        // set a unique id
        id: 'custom-date',
        is: function (s) {
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected
            return false;
        },
        format: function (s) {
            s = '' + s; //Make sure it's a string
            if (s.length == 0 || s == "&nbsp;") {
                return "ZZZ";
            }
            var hit = s.match(/(\d{2})-([A-Za-z]{3})-(\d{2})/);
            if (hit && hit.length == 4) {
                return hit[3] + months[hit[2].toUpperCase()] + hit[1];
            }
            else {
                return s;
            }
        },
        type: 'text'
    });
    LoadTaskJS();
});
```

Comment: Please could you update your question to include the specifics of what is not working for you.